# Jenkins pipeline cannot scp into remote server

Tags: ssh, jenkins-pipeline, credentials, remote-server, ssh-agent

I've got

> Hostkey verification failed

when running Jenkins declarative pipeline and using ssh agent (see logs below):

```
Started by user xxxx
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/bank_demo_back
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (deployproduction)
[Pipeline] sshagent
[ssh-agent] Using credentials root (remote_credentials)
[ssh-agent] Looking for ssh-agent implementation...
[ssh-agent]   Exec ssh-agent (binary ssh-agent on a remote machine)
$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-XXXXXXxxx/xxx.xxx
SSH_AGENT_PID=xxxx
Running ssh-add (command line suppressed)
Identity added: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/bank_demo_back@tmp/private_key_xxxxxx.key (xxxxxx@xxxx.xx)
[ssh-agent] Started.
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ scp /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/bank_demo_back/target/bank-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:

Host key verification failed.

lost connection
[Pipeline] }
$ ssh-agent -k
unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
unset SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid xxxx killed;
[ssh-agent] Stopped.
[Pipeline] // sshagent
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Below, you can see the code declaration of the stage and step used into the pipeline script :

```
stages {
        stage('deployproduction') {
            steps {
                sshagent(['remote_credentials']) {
                    
                    sh 'scp /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/bank_demo_back/target/bank-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

ssh credential named 'deployproduction' have been created using Jenkins GUI menu : Dashboare > Manage Jenkins > Credentials > Sytem > Global credentials(unrestricted)
(click the link to see the screen shot of Jenkins GUI credential creation :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUTFc.png))
I have past the remote server ssh private key "into enter directly" section.

REMARQUE : When running

```
scp /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/bank_demo_back/target/bank-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:
```

into my local machine shell, this command is working.

I have spent my entire day working arround it. for example
I tried to modify the syntax to see if it can ssh into my server ():

```
sshagent(['remote_credentials']) {
   sh 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l xxx xxxx uname -a'
}
```

It returned : Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts

REMARQUE : Jenkins is istalled on my local machine and I want the jar file to be uploaded through a declarative pipeline step command. (I don't want to deploy it manualy)

Thank's for your time.